# Windows - Using Batch file to overwrite existing batch file in specific folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

The below script I am trying to copy a batch file from the temp directory (on PC that is setup as a server) and send to a specific folder on networked machines. It copies to the host system just fine but does not to the networked machines. Note each location has 2-4 networked PCs. I ping each network machine before the copy and report the disconnect in a log. The log is clean, so the machine is connecting. I believe it is not copying because it has to overwrite the existing file but I have used /y to force the overwrite. What else am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

```
echo off

set "REGNAME=%COMPUTERNAME:~0,12%"
set "REG1NAME=%COMPUTERNAME:~0,11%1"
set "REG2NAME=%COMPUTERNAME:~0,11%2"
set "REG3NAME=%COMPUTERNAME:~0,11%3"
set "REG4NAME=%COMPUTERNAME:~0,11%4"

rem copy batch files in the RDS directory that redirect eClock and eClock1

rem copy the batch files temp to rds on REG1

copy /y c:\temp\eClock_Call.bat C:\RDS
copy /y c:\temp\eClock1_Call.bat C:\RDS

rem copy the batch files to REG2

copy /y c:\temp\eClock_Call.bat \\%REG2NAME%\C$\RDS
copy /y c:\temp\eClock1_Call.bat \\%REG2NAME%\C$\RDS

rem If REG3 exists, copy the batch file to REG3

ping %REG3NAME%

If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO :ENDSCRIPT

copy /y c:\temp\eClock_Call.bat \\%REG3NAME%\C$\RDS
copy /y c:\temp\eClock1_Call.bat \\%REG3NAME%\C$\RDS


rem If REG4 exists, copy the batch file to REG4

ping %REG4NAME%

If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO :ENDSCRIPT

copy /y c:\temp\eClock_Call.bat \\%REG4NAME%\C$\RDS
copy /y c:\temp\eClock1_Call.bat \\%REG4NAME%\C$\RDS


:ENDSCRIPT
```

Comment: You don't appear to `ping` "REG2", and if the `ping` returns errorlevel 1 for "RG3" or "REG4", you are branching to `:endscript` not to the next machine.

Comment: Thanks, every location has a minimum of 2 machines. So we expect it to connect because they talk all day long. I will add a ping line for REG2. Appreciate this feedback. Looking for more on why it may not be coping the files to REG2 and others.

Comment: `%computername%` doesn't has a space, has it? Run your script with `echo on` to see what's really executed.

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot. Looks like my security group has locked down the network machines and did not tell us! I am getting access denied but when the machine is opened, it copies just fine.